# FFMPEG How to convert pixel format using hardware acceleration

Tags: ffmpeg

recently, I have been approching to FFmpeg (libAV) framework to decode my video streams.
I use hwaccel to decode but, for the pixel conversion, I have to transfer the data from GPU to CPU and use `sws_scale` to perform the conversion.

For this reason I am wondering: What is the correct pipeline to perform also the pixel conversion on the device side? (to avoid useless GPU->CPU // CPU->GPU transfer)

Thank you in advance!
Stef.

Comment: `scale_cuda` filter has a `format` parameter that supports conversion from yuv444 to yuv420p for example, but the filter does not support converting between YUV and RGB. `scale_npp` filter may support other conversions (I don't know). That only apply NVIDIA GPUs. For AMD and Intel there may be other options. Intel HD Graphics supports `vpp_qsv` filter. What is the GPU type and what conversion are you looking for? Please post an example for FFmpeg command line with arguments.

Comment: Dear @Rotem, thank you so much for your hints (and sorry for my super late reply)! I do not have a specific code snippet to show. I've use sw_scale so far and I started just now to explore possible alternative solutions for performing HW pix conversion. I will try your suggestions and I will let you know the results. Thank you so much again!